# Проверка на правильность написания функции в Matlab

Tags: matlab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно ли я записала функцию в Матлабе?

y = ((1 + log10 (x./3) .^2)) / ((0.5 * x - exp(1) .^(x./2)))

У меня есть массив х: x = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ]

Но когда вызываю функцию у, то оно подсчитывает лишь для одного элемента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно ведь для каждого х выводить результат, а не только для одного значения. Не могу понять, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Небольшая поправка: точки перед операциями деления и умножения на скаляр можно не ставить. А решением Вашей проблемы как раз является точка перед знаком деления в середине формулы.
P.S. экспоненту можно не возводить в степень отдельной командой, достаточно указать требуемую степень в скобках после exp.